# Is it possible to align all fields when there is no error/error exist below the fields with seperate div for all (Label, Field & Error))?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Like the below image, Right now the error is showing but when one field is filled then others alignment distracted

Screenshot Example

[image: Screenshot Example]

```html
<div class="fields-wrap">
  <div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Contract Cost<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="5072dc9c-c69c-4fcb-9f77-55700faee457" name="totalContractCost" value="0.00"></span></span>
      <span
        id="errorText">Please Enter Total Contract Cost</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-wrapper field-box error-wrap"><label>Commitment<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <div width="100%" class="ComponentContainer-sc-h8azzi-2 ggmLla">
      <div class="StyledContainer-sc-h8azzi-3 bwTduI"><span class="FlexedRowContainer-sc-h8azzi-6 dNWVBd"><span class="FlexedColContainer-sc-h8azzi-7 dvhnsk"><div color="[object Object]" height="2.75rem" width="100%" class="SelectContainer-sc-h8azzi-0 ioyyCM"><select name="commitment" height="2.75rem" color="[object Object]" width="100%" label="" aria-label=" Optional Please Enter Commitment" id="ckzs5u4qo006z396aoqayn1k4" tabindex="0" class="SelectEl-sc-h8azzi-1 hsaAUl"><option value="" aria-label="Select item 1 of 3 selected" role="option">Select</option><option value="Yes" aria-label="Yes item 2 of 3 " role="option">Yes</option><option value="No" aria-label="No item 3 of 3 " role="option">No</option></select><span tabindex="-1" height="2.75rem" color="[object Object]" aria-hidden="true" class="IconContainer-sc-h8azzi-4 eWVljA"><svg data="[object Object]" aria-label="error icon" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class="StyledSVG-oulxgz-0 blTShM"><g><rect stroke="none" fill="#000000" x="11" y="16.03" width="2" height="1.98"></rect><rect vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="none" fill="none" x="4.34" y="4.34" rx="2" transform="translate(-4.97 12) rotate(-45)" width="15.31" height="15.31"></rect><polygon stroke="none" fill="#000000" points="12.33 14.04 11.66 14.04 11 10.94 11 7.02 12.99 7.02 12.99 10.94 12.33 14.04"></polygon></g></svg></span></div>
      <div
        role="alert">
        <div class="ErrorTextWrapper-sc-13aeuon-0 gGAiUl">
          <p aria-hidden="false" class="StyledTypography-sc-5k55co-0 hUtPeG StyledBody-sc-1s1yqd8-0 hHSzKm">Please Enter Commitment</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Transport MRC Over Term<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="f490f51d-02f9-4c86-9215-9b718a08da9c" name="totalTransportMrcOverTerm" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Transport MRC Over Term</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Transport NRC<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="f2db0fd1-a3ab-4374-abae-ca7822b9ee49" name="totalTransportNRC" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Transport NRC</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Transport Vendor Cost Over Term<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="ede2efe9-bc7b-40cb-99e4-821bcbc7575d" name="totalTransportVendorCostOverTerm" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Transport Vendor Cost Over Term</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Project Cost Over Term<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="a1a0f80f-d48f-4ca0-af35-e19bdbea2f43" name="totalProjectCostOverTerm" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Project Cost Over Term</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Early Termination Liability<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="1bddaf74-4306-477b-9896-b06582712f74" name="earlyTerminationLiability" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Early Termination Liability</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Projected Savings<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="0b77df5e-8324-4df6-9ef7-39af303bb745" name="projectedSavings" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Projected Savings</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Anticipated Spend<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="337c2141-b9d2-4a16-a000-aaddcd281e56" name="aniticipatedSpend" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Anticipated Spend</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Estimated Revenue<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap"><span class="k-numeric-wrap"><input tabindex="0" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="55281ab8-af4a-4d5b-acf9-a925a70c8186" name="estimatedRevenue" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Estimated Revenue</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="select-wrapper field-box error-wrap"><label>TurnKey<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div width="100%" class="ComponentContainer-sc-h8azzi-2 ggmLla">
    <div class="StyledContainer-sc-h8azzi-3 bwTduI"><span class="FlexedRowContainer-sc-h8azzi-6 dNWVBd"><span class="FlexedColContainer-sc-h8azzi-7 dvhnsk"><div color="[object Object]" height="2.75rem" width="100%" class="SelectContainer-sc-h8azzi-0 ioyyCM"><select name="turnKey" height="2.75rem" color="[object Object]" width="100%" label="" aria-label=" Optional Please Enter TurnKey" id="ckzs5u4qu0070396aco3xifw3" tabindex="0" class="SelectEl-sc-h8azzi-1 hsaAUl"><option value="" aria-label="Select item 1 of 3 selected" role="option">Select</option><option value="Yes" aria-label="Yes item 2 of 3 " role="option">Yes</option><option value="No" aria-label="No item 3 of 3 " role="option">No</option></select><span tabindex="-1" height="2.75rem" color="[object Object]" aria-hidden="true" class="IconContainer-sc-h8azzi-4 eWVljA"><svg data="[object Object]" aria-label="error icon" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false" class="StyledSVG-oulxgz-0 blTShM"><g><rect stroke="none" fill="#000000" x="11" y="16.03" width="2" height="1.98"></rect><rect vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="none" fill="none" x="4.34" y="4.34" rx="2" transform="translate(-4.97 12) rotate(-45)" width="15.31" height="15.31"></rect><polygon stroke="none" fill="#000000" points="12.33 14.04 11.66 14.04 11 10.94 11 7.02 12.99 7.02 12.99 10.94 12.33 14.04"></polygon></g></svg></span></div>
    <div
      role="alert">
      <div class="ErrorTextWrapper-sc-13aeuon-0 gGAiUl">
        <p aria-hidden="false" class="StyledTypography-sc-5k55co-0 hUtPeG StyledBody-sc-1s1yqd8-0 hHSzKm">Please Enter TurnKey</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  </span>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Vendor Real Estate<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap" aria-disabled="true"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-disabled"><input tabindex="-1" disabled="" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="e787533b-af75-4e14-a479-4d614700aaac" name="totalRealEstateVendor" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Vendor Real Estate</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Real Estate MRC<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap" aria-disabled="true"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-disabled"><input tabindex="-1" disabled="" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="5776e69c-6332-4a5b-bfce-bb2b8deb61ff" name="totalRealEstateMrc" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Real Estate MRC</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-box error-wrap"><label>Total Real Estate NRC<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div><span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox non-vds-intput error-wrap" aria-disabled="true"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-disabled"><input tabindex="-1" disabled="" placeholder="0.00" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" type="tel" class="k-input k-formatted-value" id="de758315-6f2c-4cc1-8ce6-60f6a31e81a8" name="totalRealEstateNrc" value="0.00"></span></span>
    <span
      id="errorText">Please Enter Total Real Estate NRC</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, its all on one line now and unreadable.

Comment: Howdy vishal, can you help out potential answerers by limiting the amount of code you post to just the smallest, most relevant bits.  As is, it's hard to see or reproduce your issue in any meaningful way, so you're not likely to get great advice.